# How to check if a specific value exist in a session array

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Hi I have a list of id values i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6. When I store any of this values in to a session variable array. For example say we store 4 and 2 in the array

```
$_SESSION['value'] = array();
$_SESSION['value'][] = 4;
$_SESSION['value'][] = 2;
$_SESSION['value'][] = 6;
```

How can I check to if 2 is in the array and return true or false if its not in the array?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Any array can be checked for values with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) :

```
if ( in_array(4, $_SESSION['value']) ) {
    //do something
}
```

> in_array(needle, haystack_array)

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to check that:

```
in_array($valueToCheck, $_SESION["value"])
```

Maybe it´s a good idea to check too if the array is setted in session:

```
function check($valueToCheck){
return ((isset($_SESSION["value"]) && is_array($_SESSION["value"]) && in_array($valueToCheck, $_SESION["value"]));
}
```